# jsp program in executing the sql query

Tags: mysql, jsp

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add where bno='111'' at line 1

```
String sql1="select * from add where bno='"+bno+"'";
```

This is the code  where add is the table name and bno is of type varchar

Comment: Without seeing you table names and the full code it would be difficult to give a definitive answer.  But I'll say that you avoid concatenating your `WHERE` clause because it leaves the door open for SQL injection.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - `add` is a reserved word. Consider using back ticks or renaming your table.

Comment: is your `bno` a text type or numeric type?